# How can I add icon/link to Panel?

Tags: 12.10, gnome-panel

[image]

How can I add shortcut icon to Panel? I use Ubuntu 12.10

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add icons like you used to in Gnome 2.
An icon ends up there if it's a notification.
You can add icons to the Unity's dock (on the left), by right clicking on an open application's icon, and selecting "lock to launcher"

This link might be helpful:

[What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Answer (score 1):

Unity is not Gnome and the top bar is not a gnome-panel. As far as I know there is no way to add applications there. It is only made for indicators. Applications can only be docked to the launcher on the left side (right click->Lock to Launcher).

If you don't like Unity you have some alternatives to get the Gnome2 look again. There is the [MATE desktop](http://mate-desktop.org/) which continues the development of the old Gnome2. I think the better choice is [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) which is a Gnome3 fork. It aims to basically look like Gnome2 but with some of the benefits the new Gnome3 offers.

In my experience, sadly both don't work to well with Ubuntu. I would recommend [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/index.php), which is based on Ubuntu and comes in editions with MATE and Cinnamon.

Comment: gnome-fallback ftw.

Comment: There is no gnome-fallback since 11.10 anymore. That's when I "got forced" to use Unity. Now I actually work faster with it than with gnome2 :-)

Comment: I think `gnome-session-fallback` still works, I'm running 12.04 and I still use it. I can't use unity because of a virtualbox bug. :/

Comment: It is not working in 12.10